# Regular expressiont to filter file names containing .part or .temp fails

Tags: javascript, regex

I am busy with a node/express app where I am trying to ignore all file names containing .part or .temp as part of the file name.  The regular expression I wrote completely fails for some reason...  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

my Regex:

```
/[xyz]*\.part+|\.temp+\/
```

Comment: What is the `[xyz]*` part for?

Comment: Yeah, remove that `[xyz]*`, `/\.(?:part|temp)/` should be enough.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder isn't that the character set consisting of all non speciall characters?

Comment: @user2094257: Um....no...not at all. Suggest [reading up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FRegular_Expressions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plug your expression into regex101.com or similar, you should see the problem.

If you want to filter out filenames containing `.part` or `.temp`:

```
if (!/\.(?:part|temp)/.test(filename)) {
    // Doesn't have it, the name's okay
}
```

Or it could be `/\.part|\.temp/` if you prefer. (And that is a bit simpler to understand...)

Example with tests:

```js
var tests = [
  {str: "foo", expect: true},
  {str: "foo.part", expect: false},
  {str: ".partfoo", expect: false},
  {str: "foo.partfoo", expect: false},
  {str: "bar", expect: true},
  {str: "bar.temp", expect: false},
  {str: ".tempbar", expect: false},
  {str: "bar.tempbar", expect: false}
];
tests.forEach(function(entry) {
  var result = !/\.(?:part|temp)/.test(entry.str);
  if (result == entry.expect) {
    console.log("'" + entry.str + "' => " + result + " GOOD");
  } else {
    console.log("'" + entry.str + "' => " + result + " ERROR should be " + entry.expect);
  }
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Crowder that doesn't work at all.  my code:  var watcher = chokidar.watch('./downloads', {
 ignored: '/\.(?:part|temp)/',
 persistent: true
});

Comment: @user2094257: Then it's to do with `chokidar.watch`. The regex does what you said you wanted it to do. See the tests I added to the answer.